# ReactJS Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setstate

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputAuthor: '',
      inputText: '',
      authorIsEmpty: true,
      textIsEmpty: true
    };
    this.BtnClick = this.BtnClick.bind(this);
  }
```

```
BtnClick(e) {
      fetch('http://localhost:80/add-news', {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(function (res) {
          if (res) {
            this.setState({
              inputAuthor: '',
              inputText: '',
              authorIsEmpty: true,
              textIsEmpty: true
            });
          } else {
            console.log('Ответ сервера ' + res.status + ': ' + res.statusText);
          }
        })
        .catch(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
        });
    }
  }
```

После успешного ответа от сервера, я пытаюсь изменить state, но получаю ошибку. Подскажите мне как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция, которую вы используете как callback для промиса имеет свой собственный контекст. Вам необходимо заменить её на стрелочную:

```
    .then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.setState({
          inputAuthor: '',
          inputText: '',
          authorIsEmpty: true,
          textIsEmpty: true
        });
      } else {
        console.log('Ответ сервера ' + res.status + ': ' + res.statusText);
      }
    })
```